# Not able to Delete a record from Parent table having child records even after having Cascade All enabled

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, cascading-deletes

I have a table Department with one to many mapping to Employee table and having cascade type as all.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="department",orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private List<Employee> emp;
```

---

In database , the child table(Employee) is having this constraint on foreign Key
[image]

---

When Iam deleting a record from Department Table in Java Code , Using Hibernate *Delete Function with a Primary key as parameter,*it is Deleting the record from Department table as well as deleting all associated records to it in Employee Table.
When Iam running below query (Dep_ref is not primaryKey)

```
delete from Department where Dep_ref= 99999;
```

So it *should delete all records from Department Table, and associated records in Employee table.*
**But**,Iam getting below error.

> SQL Error: ORA-02292: integrity constraint violated - child record
>   found
>   02292. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - child record found"
>   *Cause:    attempted to delete a parent key value that had a foreign
>              dependency.
>   *Action:   delete dependencies first then parent or disable constraint.

Can anyone Please Help me out to Fix this issue.

Comment: Try initializing your `emp` collection: `private List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<>();` and make sure it's fetched when you delete the `Department` (since it's lazy).

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your mapping. It is in the  wrong direction. You should create the  foreign key on Employee to reference Department.

```
// Departments
@OneToMany(mappedBy="departments", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Employee> emp;

// Employee
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="department_id" , referencedColumnName="id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Departments department;
```